# Java session - can not convert to void

Tags: java, session

I am trying to extend/control the session life in my application.

Currently its like this.

```
request.getSession(true);
```

and I've seen examples that indicate you can use this method.

```
request.getSession(true).setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); //in seconds;
```

but I get the following error

```
cannot convert from void to HttpSession
```

Comment: setMaxInactiveInterval() does not return a value.  Pls post your real code.

Comment: Are you trying to assign the result of setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60) to a HttpSession variable?

Comment: obviously you are trying `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true).setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);` which is wrong .

Comment: I see now --  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true) ;
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60) ; // 10 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an `HttpSession` variable (for further use later), you have to assign the `getSession` result to the variable and *then* call `setMaxInactiveInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a method on `HttpServletRequest` and returns an `HttpSession`

`public HttpSession getSession(boolean create)`

The second is a method call on `HttpSession` itself and does not return anything. It's a setter.

`public void setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`